# Memory errors after moving from Visual Studio 2010 to 2012

Tags: visual-c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2012

My library was working fine in Visual Studio 2010 but now whenever I run it compiled in 2012, I get these memory errors:

```
First-chance exception at 0x76884B32 in Example.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0101F3A0.
First-chance exception at 0x76884B32 in Example.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0101F3A0.
Unhandled exception at at 0x76884B32 in Example.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0101F3A0.
First-chance exception at 0x76FF3541 (ntdll.dll) in Example.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFEFEFF02.
```

According to the call stack, the errors are coming up everytime `return wstring(cMD5.hexdigest());` is called from the following code:

```
wstring GetMachineHash() {
     BYTE szHash[48];
     LPBYTE pIdentifierHash;

     ZeroMemory(szHash, 48);

     MachineNameIdentifier cNameId;
     pIdentifierHash = cNameId.GetIdentifierHash();

     memcpy(szHash, pIdentifierHash, 16);

     NetworkAdapterIdentifier cNetAdaptId;
     pIdentifierHash = cNetAdaptId.GetIdentifierHash();

     memcpy(szHash+16, pIdentifierHash, 16);

     VolumeInfoIdentifier cVolInfo;
     pIdentifierHash = cVolInfo.GetIdentifierHash();

     memcpy(szHash+32, pIdentifierHash, 16);

     MD5 cMD5(szHash, 48);

     return wstring(cMD5.hexdigest());
}
```

If your wondering what MD5 class I'm using, its the one port by Frank Thilo but its modified to return LPBYTE instead of std::string like so:

```
// return 16 byte md5 hash
LPBYTE MD5::hash() const {
    if (!finalized)
        return 0;

    return (LPBYTE)digest;
}

// return hex representation of digest as string
LPTSTR MD5::hexdigest() const
{
    if (!finalized)
        return NULL;

    LPTSTR szBuf = new TCHAR[33];

    ZeroMemory(szBuf, 33);

    for (int i=0; i<16; i++)
        _stprintf_s(szBuf+i*2, 33, _T("%02X"), digest[i]);

    szBuf[32]=0;

    return szBuf;
}
```

After doing some research here on SO, it says these errors are because of a possible memory leak somewhere else in my program. But I have looked and everything seems to be freed correctly. Any ideas? I was wondering if this also might have something to do with calling a DLL library from an EXE through `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()`?

(I should also note that the Platform Toolset is set to `Visual Studio 2012 - Windows XP (v110_xp)`)

Comment: @tofutim Yes, it looks like it was from errors with allocating memory in my code and also partially from moving to Visual Studio 2012.